Problem loading Picasso in build.gradle.kts
So I am just now trying to make a full transition from Java to Kotlin on android studio one of the libraries I use most but every time i add it to build.gradle.kts I get this error
Dependencies using groupId com.android.support and androidx.* can not be combined but found com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0 and androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1 incompatible dependencies


How did I fix this?
I tried to change the core:core-ktx version I had the same error

Picasso is dead, you may encounter dependency problems. Consider Coil, Fresco or Glide.
